# Using JTAPI on a linux server... Is there any possibility?

Tags: linux, tapi, jtapi

I implemented a TAPI interface in java with the generic GJTAPI 1.8 library.
Everything is working fine on windows, but on linux I can´t get the provider with getProvider(...), because there will be used the **Tapi3Provider.dll** file...

Is there any solution to use it on Linux?